# Weird Issue With argv in if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, string-comparison, argv

I'm having problems with argv in an if statement in one of my C programs. I know I must be missing something simple and stupid (it's been a while since I've done anything in C). Problem is, it won't doOtherStuff() if I specify nothing else on the command line. Even if I do ./a.out -i it still runs doStuff(). Does anyone see what might be missing here? Thank you a lot in advance!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

    if(argv[1] == "-a" || "-A")
    {
       doStuff();
    }
    else
    {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare strings in C you have to use methods like strcmp: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

In C a string is actually an array of characters, so you are comparing the memory address of the 2 arrays (which will be different of course since they are different arrays).

Comment: Oh, duh. I completely forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: In case you're curious, the reason `doStuff()` was always being called was because of the incorrect use of `||`: the clause `argv[1] == "-a"` will always fail because it's not a valid way of comparing strings, and the pointers to each string will never be the same. However, the solitary `"-A"` will always be true, because it has a non-zero address, meaning your `if` statement will always evaluate to true as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing C-strings with the *equality operator* (`==`).

You have to use the [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function instead (defined in `string.h`).

Like:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-a") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "-A") == 0)
    {
        doStuff();
    }
    else
    {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Note that string comparison is one of the most basics operation in programming, and your `if` statement wasn't correct as well. Try to read more about the basics if you are not already doing it.